# how to find specific instruction using bit field? (bit comparison)

Tags: c

I want to find type of instruction(16-bit).

For example Type 0 instruction, it always has its leftmost two bit is 0.

0 0 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? (16-bit bit field; ? is don't care)

I want to find this type 0 instruction using only leftmost two bit.

What should I do? (C language)

Ultimately, I wanna find that an instruction(such as 0012345678910111 or 0098765432123456) is type 0 instruction.

Sorry for my english T_T.

I want some code like below (in Java)

```
if (instruction.containsBit(type0) == true)
```

Comment: use the c bit operands: &, |, ^

Comment: You need to read about the bitwise instructions `|` (bitwise or), `&` (bitwise and) and `^` (bitwise xor). Also read about the bitwise shift operator `<<` and `>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `&` (bitwise AND) to mask out the relevant bits, then `==` to do the comparison:

```
uint16_t opcode = 0xf001;

if((opcode & 0xc000) == 0)
{
  printf("opcode 0x%0x has topmost two bits cleared", opcode);
}
```

The `0xc000` constant, typically called "the mask" in code like this, is `1100 0000 0000 0000` in binary, so when applied with the bitwise AND, it will result in a number having 1s where *both* arguments have 1s. Comparing the result to 0 makes sure the `opcode` does *not* have any 1s in locations where the mask has 1s.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `&` in C can perform an simple AND operation. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).
Then you just need the bitmask of the bits you want to check on the right-side of this operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  unsigned short a = 0x7FFF;
  unsigned short b = 0x80FF;
  if( a & 0x8000 ) printf("a Highest bit set\n");
  if( a & 0x4000 ) printf("a Second highest bit set\n");
  if( b & 0x8000 ) printf("b Highest bit set\n");
  if( b & 0x4000 ) printf("b Second highest bit set\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define true ((uint8_t)1)
#define false ((uint8_t)0)

uint8_t IsThisInstructionType0(uint16_t instruction)
{
    uint16_t andMask = 0x8000;
    if(((instruction & andMAsk) >> 15) == 0)
    {
        andMask >>= 1;
        if( ( ((instruction & andMAsk) << 1) >> 15 ) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int GetInstructionClass (uint16_t ins)
{
  return (ins>>14)&3;
}
```

This expression: `(ins>>14)&3` works like this:

First, `ins` has this format:

`C C X X X X X X X X X X X X X X`

Where `C` are the bits that form the instruction class. `X` means "don't care for now".

The first operation, `>>14` shifts the number to the right so it ends like this:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 C C`

Note that as we are using an `uint16_t`, the shift operation should enter 0's from the left, but as the function result is `int`, and `int` is signed, I'm not sure if the type promotion happens before of after the shifting is performed. I'd say that the type promotion happens after the evaluation of the whole expression.

Anyway, and just to be sure that no unwanted bits will be returned, we will mask the result of the shifting so that only bits 0 and 1 are preserved. The mask is:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1`  which is 3.

So the final result will be a number with bits 0 and 1 being the same as bits 14 and 15 of the original `ins` argument, giving 0, 1, 2 or 3 (I repeat: I'm assuming that the whole expression is being treated as a 16 bit number). This works with MinGW, Visual C++ and GCC in a 32-bit environment.